# $f$ uniformly continuous, $f_n(x) = f(x + 1/n)$. Show $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$. Why is uniform continuity needed?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, sequence-of-function

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f_n(x) = f(x + \frac{1}{n})$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

I have seen many proofs of this online, but I am wondering if the requirement that $f$ be uniformly continuous is necessary. Could we weaken this to continuity?

Suppose $f$ is continuous. Then

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. whenever $|x - y| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

I want to show $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

Now, consider $g_n(x) = x - \frac{1}{n}$ and $g(x) = x$. Choose $N = \frac{1}{\delta}$. Then,

$|g_n(x) - g(x)| = |x + \frac{1}{n} - x| = |\frac{1}{n}| < \frac{1}{N} < \delta$

Now, here is where the other proofs use uniform continuity. Since $\delta$ could depend on $x$, uniform continuity would be needed to ensure $N$ does not depend on $x$. However, let's start from a different approach.

I know $g_n(x) = x + \frac{1}{n}$ converges uniformly to $g(x) = x$. In case this needs justification, forget about the $\delta$ above for a moment.

I want to show $\forall \rho > 0, \exists N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N_{1}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, |g_n(x) - g(x)| < \rho$.

Fix $\rho > 0$ Choose $N = \frac{1}{\rho}$. Then,
$|g_n(x) - g(x)| = |x + \frac{1}{n} - x| = |\frac{1}{n}| < \frac{1}{N} < \rho$

Therefore, $g_n$ is uniformly convergent.
This $\rho$, unlike $\delta$ from before, will definitely not depend on $x$ due to uniform convergence of $g_n$. Therefore, I can take $\delta = \rho$ in the definition of continuity, and this choice of $\delta$ will work because indeed $|g_n(x) - g(x)| < \rho = \delta$. I will also choose $N = N_{1}$. This would imply

$|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

and then by substitution,

$|f(x_n) - f(x)| = |f(x + \frac{1}{n}) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

Therefore, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Considering how many times this question has been asked, I am assuming I went wrong somewhere. Does anyone see where my "proof" without uniform continuity would fall apart?

This is different from this question [If $f(x+1/n)$ converges to a continuous function $f(x)$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, is $f(x)$ necessarily uniformly continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916380/if-fx1-n-converges-to-a-continuous-function-fx-uniformly-on-mathbbr) as this one starts with $f_n$ converging uniformly. I am trying to start from the other side.

Comment: Well have you tried checking what happens with $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: If $f(x) = x^2$ then $f(x + 1/n) - f(x) = (x+1/n)^2 - x^2 = 2x/n - 1/n^2$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$ for any value of $n$. So convergence is not uniform.

Comment: @JairTaylor hold on, why would that be unbounded? $n$ is a natural number, so wouldn't that tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$? Now, I do agree that is certainly a counterexample. The choice of $N$ would depend on $x$. If you're ok clearing up the unbounded part, please feel free to post this as an answer! I will accept it.

Comment: @NolanP Well, this is just a line of slope $2/n$. So for any fixed $n$, it will tend to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.  So given $M>1$ arbitrarily large, you can choose eg $x = Mn$ and then $2x/n - 1/n^2 = 2M - 1/n^2 > M$.

Comment: Remember that in the definition of uniform continuity, the bound you get on $|f_n(x) -f(x)|$ has to depend only on $n$ and work for *any* x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me restate my comment as an answer: you should follow through the logic using a concrete example like $f(x) = x^2$ to see exactly where the argument fails.

Comment: See Jair Taylor's comments on the original post for the details to this.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is only continuous and not uniformly continuous, then $\delta$ needs to depend on $x$ and $\epsilon$.  If $\delta$ doesn't depend on either of them, then you cannot use it in the definition of $f$ being continuous.  You've created a $\delta$ that doesn't depend on either of $x$ or $\epsilon$, so it cannot be applied to the definition.

In other words, your "proof" falls apart right here:

> Therefore, **I can take $\delta = \rho$ in the definition of continuity,**
>
> [...]
>
> I will also choose $N = N_{1}$. **This would imply**
>
> $|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

The "This would imply" isn't true, because the definition of continuity gives you a $\delta$.  It cannot be chosen.

---

**An addendum:** After a lengthy comment thread, it has become apparent to me that the issue is one of mixing up the semantics of the existential quantifier $\exists$.  I'll try to be as explicit as possible using the logical syntax to guide us:

- Suppose we want to show that $f$ is continuous for an appropriately given $f$ (note this is not the context of the current problem).  That is, we want to show $$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \forall x, \exists \delta > 0, \forall y, \Big(|x-y| < \delta \longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon\Big)$$ To show this, we let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, then we let $x$ be arbitrary, and then we find some $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$ for any $y$ such that $|x-y| < \delta.$

Much of the work in proving $f$ is continuous, therefore, comes from finding an appropriate value/formula for $\delta$.  In a sense, we must choose $\delta>0$ (often as a function of $\epsilon$ and $x$) specifically so that the definition works.

- Suppose now that we are *given* that $f$ is continuous and we want to prove something else.  Then how can we utilize the given truth of $$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \forall x, \exists \delta > 0, \forall y, \Big(|x-y| < \delta \longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon\Big)?$$  This time, we may choose any $\varepsilon > 0$ we want and choose any $x$ we want (sometimes these may be arbitrary and other times they may be very particular values; it all depends on what you're trying to prove).  However, we *cannot* choose $\delta > 0$.  Ultimately, all the assumption that $f$ is continuous tells us is that there is *some* $\delta > 0$ that works for the given choice of $\varepsilon$ and $x$ without telling us anything about it's value.  Therefore, we must let $\delta > 0$ be fixed but unknown to us; all we know is that if $|x-y| < \delta$, then we'd have $|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$ (and how this applies to the proof would depend on what we're trying to prove).

This is the context we find ourselves in for the problem being asked.  In particular, as mentioned above, we may choose $\varepsilon > 0$ (in the usual proof, this is arbitrary but chosen as part of the definition of "$f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$") but we **cannot** choose $\delta > 0$.

*As a sidenote, even though we cannot choose $\delta$ in this type of situation, we can still derive some specific properties for it.  For instance, once we have the unknown $\delta > 0$, we can take any smaller value and it'll still work.  This is how we can, for instance, replace $\delta$ with the minimum of $\delta$ and $1/2$ in order to assume $0 < \delta \leq 1/2$, but even in this case, we're almost always dealing with a fixed but unknown value for $\delta$.*

Comment: Ok, how about this then. Since the uniform convergence of $g_n$ holds $\forall \rho > 0$, what if I take $\rho = \epsilon$? In this case, I would have $\delta$ in terms of only $\epsilon$. Also, I am in a bit of a disagreement here with you saying that $\delta$ NEEDS to depend on $x$ and $\epsilon$. Uniform continuity implies continuity. So, if you take any uniformly continuous function, it is continuous. Therefore, that is a continuous function with $\delta$ only depending on $\epsilon$ and not $x$.

Comment: @NolanP I have added more in order to clarify.  The point is that for a continuous function, you may choose $x$ and $\epsilon > 0$, but you cannot choose $\delta$.  As for your disagreement, it's not well-placed, as I am specifically talking about continuous functions that aren't uniformly continuous, and in that case, $\delta$ necessarily depends on both $\epsilon$ and $x$ (and $f$) -- you cannot break this dependence.

Comment: I'm sorry, you've made me more confused. When proving functions are continuous, we always choose a $\delta$. We aim to find a $\delta$ that works. That's always how we prove things are continuous. Here, I have found a $\delta$ that works for $g_n$. If we cannot choose $\delta$, then I am now completely unsure of how any continuity proofs are valid.

Comment: For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264081/prove-x-mapsto-x2-is-continuous. In the answer, he chose the value of $\delta$.

Comment: @NolanP You're mixing up the strategy to prove that a function is continuous (in which we let $\epsilon > 0, x$ be arbitrary and find a $\delta$ depending on $\epsilon, x$) with **using the assumption that a function is continuous** (as in the current problem), in which we may choose $\epsilon > 0, x$, but have no control at all on $\delta$.  $\delta$ is just some value that makes the $|x - y| < \delta \longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ true for that pair $x,\epsilon$.

Comment: @Noal P You choose a $\delta$ that works *given* $x$ and $\epsilon$. If you are not given these then you cannot choose $\delta$. If you can indeed choose $\delta$ independent of $x$, then the function is uniformly continuous by definition. For example, every continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @BrianMoehring what you're saying seems to imply exactly what I am trying to get. I found a $\delta$ that works for a specific $g_n, \epsilon$. Now, Enforce is correct in that the function turned out to be uniformly continuous; however, I did not start with this assumption.

Comment: @NolanP You can take $\rho = \epsilon$ if you like. This will not change anything. $\delta$ will now depend on $\rho$ and $x$.

Comment: @Enforce can you explicitly show how $\delta$ depends on $\rho$ and $x$? My $\rho$ does not depend on $x$, so by choosing it equal $\delta$, it's seem intuitively impossible that it will depend on $x$. How can something equal to another thing be such that one of them involves $x$? Can you please show that explicitly?

Comment: @NolanP Your $\delta$ also doesn't depend on $f$, which should **really** be a red flag!  Again, if you're using the assumption that $f$ is continuous, then $\delta$ is not something you can choose.  You may pick $f$, $\epsilon > 0$, and $x$, but $\delta$ is given by the property that $f$ is continuous.  You are mixing up proving $f$ is continuous for a particular $f$ with using it as an assumption for an arbitrary $f$, and your refusal to recognize the distinction is making even the questions in your comments complete nonsense.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'm sorry, you've completely lost me. None of this conversation is making any sense, and I almost feel like your comments are implying my answer is correct, yet you are claiming they don't. We DO pick $\delta$, that's how the proofs work. I sent a link in the chat. If we can't choose $\delta$, then no continuity proofs would work, period. What you are saying sounds like complete nonsense to me. I cannot accept this answer, I apologize. If you would like to try to make it more clear please feel free, but in its current form I am completely lost and very confused.

Comment: @NolanP "We DO pick $\delta$, that's how the proofs work. I sent a link in the chat." -- That is how the proofs _that a function is continuous_ work.  That's _not_ how proofs work that _use that a function is continuous_.  Perhaps considering the abstract logical context would help:  If we want to prove that $\exists x, P(x)$ is true, then we choose an $a$ such that $P(a)$ is true.  This shows $\exists x, P(x)$.  What if, instead, we are _given_ that $\exists x, P(x)$ is true?  Can we choose an $x$?  Not necessarily.  Rather, we let $a$ denote _something_ such that $P(a)$ is true.

Comment: Here, the assumption that $f$ is continuous takes the form $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \forall x, \exists \delta > 0, P(\epsilon, x, \delta)$$  If we want to use this, we may choose $\epsilon > 0$ and $x$, but then we have $$\exists \delta > 0, P(\epsilon, x, \delta)$$ Using this type of logical sentence doesn't allow us to choose $\delta$.  We must allow $\delta$ to be whatever it is that makes $P(\epsilon, x, \delta)$ true.  If we knew $f$, perhaps we could find a function $\delta = \delta(x,\epsilon)$ giving $\delta$, but since we don't know $f$ here, $\delta$ exists but cannot be chosen by us

Comment: @NolanP I've edited the post more to show the distinction between proving and using that a function is continuous.  It should be pretty easy to see where in your proof is the error by following the others' advice of considering $f(x) = x^2$, but if you're still wondering why it's not working, then try to read my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

**"Suppose $f$ is continuous. Then**

**$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. whenever $|x - y| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$"**

Here if you only assume continuous (Not UC), then your $\delta$ might depend on the point you choose, for example if you study the continuity at some point $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\delta=\delta_\epsilon(x)$. Hence your $N$ depends on $x$, so you can't say $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly. Because UC requires your $N$ is independent of the choices for point $x$.

---

Proof for OP with UC condition:

$f(x)$ is uniformly continuous, which means

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta_\epsilon, \forall x,y, ~|x-y|<\delta_\epsilon\rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon \tag{*}$$

Now, take $N_\epsilon=\lfloor\frac{1}{\delta_\epsilon}\rfloor+1$,

$$~\forall n>N_\epsilon \Rightarrow n> \lfloor\frac{1}{\delta_\epsilon}\rfloor+1\ge\frac{1}{\delta_\epsilon}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}<\delta_\epsilon$$

$$\Rightarrow \left|\left(x+\frac{1}n\right)-x\right|=\frac{1}{n}<\delta_\epsilon$$

$$ ~|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon~~~~~~\text{by Eq.}(*)$$

Therefore, $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly.